# Add scroll view to the whole activity

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-xml

I want my whole activity to scroll. My activity contains a view pager and a gridview. I have read at various places that a scroll view does not work properly if there is a gridview in the layout. But, I want this to happen. Is there a way out?

xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFF">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar2"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar2"
        ></include>
  <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
android:id="@+id/imgbtn">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:background="#FFF">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

  <Button
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:text="@string/left"
android:background="@drawable/btn_back"
android:textColor="#FFF"
android:onClick="sleft"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pager"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pager"
android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:id="@+id/left"

/>
   <TableRow
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pager"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pager"
android:paddingRight="30dp"
android:paddingBottom="15dp"
>
         <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="+"
             android:textColor="#FFF"

             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/numb"
        android:background="@drawable/button_back"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:textColor="#000"

    android:text="0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/minus"
    android:id="@+id/numb"
    />
        <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:text="-"
            android:background="@drawable/button_back"
         />
        </TableRow>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="-)"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_back"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pager"

            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:onClick="sright"
            android:id="@+id/right"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="185dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgbtn"
        >

    </GridView>


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.food.foodjugaad.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />



    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The output that i get from this code does not apply the scroll view like i want. Grid view and view pager work separately. and also, there occurs a white space at the bottom of the screen.

This is what I am getting -

[image]